# Question is not coming from opentdb api since a long time

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**Problem:** I'm running my quiz app from the opentdb api for the question but it does not show the question it's still loading the page for long time

**Here is my code:**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { CircularProgress } from "@mui/material";
import Question from "../../components/Question/Question";
import "./Quiz.css";

const Quiz = ({ name, question, score, setScore, setQuestion }) => {
  const [option, setOption] = useState();

  const [currQues, setCurrQues] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    setOption(
      question &&
        handleShuffle([
          question[currQues]?.correct_answer,

          ...question[currQues]?.incorrect_answer,
        ])
    );
  }, [currQues, question]);

  console.log(question);

  const handleShuffle = (option) => {
    return option.sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5);
  };

  return (
    <div className="quiz">
      <span className="subtitle">Welcome, {name}</span>

      {question ? (
        <>
          <div className="quizInfo">
            <span>{question[currQues].category}</span>

            <span>
              {}
              Score : {score}
            </span>
          </div>

          <Question
            currQues={currQues}
            setCurrQues={setCurrQues}
            question={question}
            option={option}
            correct={question[currQues]?.correct_answer}
            score={score}
            setQuestion={setQuestion}
          />
        </>
      ) : (
        <CircularProgress
          style={{ margin: 100 }}
          color="inherit"
          size={150}
          thickness={1}
        />
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Quiz;
```

Please help me out to debugged the issue or mistakes I have made and helped me to resolved the same.

Comment: Please share your code in codesandbox. So, we can look into the issue in more detailed way and helped you out.